# AVAudioRecorder url as data failing

Tags: swift, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to upload an audio file recorded. I can see the file in my simulator & play it, but in my code, it's coming up as nil.

```
func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
    if success {
        let theURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: audioRecorder.url.absoluteString)
        do {
            let myData:NSData = try NSData(contentsOf: theURL)
            print("\n", theURL, theURL, myData)
        } catch
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “recording.mp4” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/file:/Users/edolecki/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/161015F2-EE0D-4355-BE53-092DA2129967/data/Containers/Data/Application/B656393D-FE0E-40E4-8713-AA923B8AF17C/Documents/recording.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000245940 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I have navigated to the simulator location, and indeed the newly recorded mp4 is there. I can play it. I need to send the file to a PHP script, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: Most likely your not setting up your path correctly if you know the file is there but it can’t find it

Comment: Why are you creating a 2nd URL from your first one?

Comment: @bolnad if I print the URL it's correct.

Comment: I believe I need to do this (which I cannot test yet as I am traveling):.                                                          let file: FileHandle? = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: audioRecorder.url.absoluteString)   if file != nil {   let data = file?.readDataToEndOfFile()